# Sql Server Displaying Items in specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a list of items

**ItemName  Manufacturer  TopSalesUnit**

```
Item1     A             100   
Item2     A             80                      
Item3     A             60
Item4     B             70   
Item5     B             50   
Item6     B             30
Item7     C             10       
Item8     C             05
```

I would like the records to be ordered so that the highest TopSalesUnit item is shown first, then the next highest item from a different manufacturer is shown second, then the next highest item from
a third manufacturer is shown, etc.:

**ItemName    Manufacturer  TopSalesUnit**

```
Item1       A             100    
Item4       B             070
Item7       C             010 
Item2       A             080
Item5       B             050 
Item8       C             005   
Item3       A             060 
Item6       B             030
```

How to write a query in T-SQL to achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (ItemName varchar(10), Manufacturer char(1), TopSalesUnit int)

INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item1','A ',100)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item2','A ',80)                 
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item3','A ',60)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item4','B ',70)   
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item5','B ',50)   
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item6','B ',30)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item7','C ',10)       
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item8','C ',05)

SELECT
    dt.ItemName,dt.Manufacturer,dt.TopSalesUnit
    FROM (SELECT
              ItemName,Manufacturer,TopSalesUnit,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Manufacturer ORDER BY TopSalesUnit DESC) AS RowNumber
              FROM @YourTable
         ) dt 
    ORDER BY dt.RowNumber,dt.Manufacturer
```

OUTPUT:

```
ItemName   Manufacturer TopSalesUnit
---------- ------------ ------------
Item1      A            100
Item4      B            70
Item7      C            10
Item2      A            80
Item5      B            50
Item8      C            5
Item3      A            60
Item6      B            30

(8 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Is that quite right, I think your order by is the wrong way around.

Comment: @Paul Hadfield, Yes, I just added the `DESC` to the ORDER BY

Comment: SQL2005 and up (I don't think the question specified a version?)   +1 in any case.

Comment: Sorry for missing the version,version is 2005

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items b
    WHERE b.Manufacturer = Items.Manufacturer
    AND b.TopSalesUnit > Items.TopSalesUnit )
    AS RankInManufacturer
FROM Items
ORDER BY RankInManufacturer, TopSalesUnit DESC
```

This adds a new computed column that ranks the "TopSalesUnit" fields within each "Manufacturer".

Comment: +1: But there's a risk of ties having duplicate values when using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Using KM's Post I think he had close to what you want but in the proper order

```
    DECLARE @YourTable table (ItemName varchar(10), Manufacturer char(1), TopSalesUnit int)

INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item1','A ',100)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item2','A ',80)                 
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item3','A ',60)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item4','B ',70)   
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item5','B ',50)   
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item6','B ',30)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item7','C ',10)       
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Item8','C ',05)

select
    ItemName
    ,Manufacturer
    ,TopSalesUnit
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TopSalesUnit desc) as rn
    ,rank() over (partition by manufacturer order by TopSalesUnit desc) as rankcost
from
    @YourTable 

order by rankcost, rn
```

Results in:

```
Item1   A   100 1   1
Item4   B   70  3   1
Item7   C   10  7   1
Item2   A   80  2   2
Item5   B   50  5   2
Item8   C   5   8   2
Item3   A   60  4   3
Item6   B   30  6   3
```